# Как правильно уменьшить число запросов к Google Places Autocomplete API?

Tags: android, google-api, autocomplete, google-places-api

Вот этим кодом получаем подсказки названий улиц/мест

```
PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> results =
    Places.GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions(
        mGoogleApiClient,
        "Екатеринбург " + constraint.toString() + "10.",
        MY_KKORDINATNAYA_OBLAST, mPlaceFilter);
```

Я хочу перед запросом добавить информации в `constraint`, чтобы было меньше запросов.

Допустим, я знаю город и номер дома — я хочу подставить эти данные в запрос, чтобы быстрее вылетал верный вариант. Я это делаю вот так

```
"Екатеринбург " + constraint.toString() + " 10."
```

Так я намереваюсь быстрее и за меньшее число запросов получить адрес

> Екатеринбург Малышева 10.

Но судя по всему — неправильно: скорее всего, здесь должны стоять не пробелы, а какие-то правильные спецсимволы (типа `&`, `%`, ...).

Есть у кого-нибудь мысли, как составить этот запрос правильно? Или может кто-то знает, как выглядит стандартный `constraint` перед отправкой к API Google?